# update in PPTX slide (for example text and image)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, powerpoint

i have 1 PPTX file which have only 1 slide 
in that slide there are 2 text object and 1 image object

text 1 : test 1
text 2 : test 2
Image : some image

for example what i want is i want to change test 1 to test 111
i want to update text and image as well

Comment: So what have you tried so far, and where exactly are you stuck? Please show us the code of your current attempt, and indicate where exactly you're having problems.

Comment: thanks @bassfader for the response, what earlier i did is i go with Spire.Presentation with this all working fine but in PPTX slide comes with some extra text like **Evaluation Warning : The document was created with  Spire.Presentation for .NET** so i require free version. if you have any idea then please let me know